# Permission denied to github-actions[bot]

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I'm using mkdocs to generate documents for my project,now I can't deploy those docs to Github pages,it tell me:

> remote: Permission to XXX.git denied to github-actions[bot].
> fatal: unable to access 'XXX': The requested URL returned error: 403

This is my [*`CI`* config](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zyw2y8jW5M).

And my secrets of the repository:(The two `GIT_ACTIONS_PUSH` are all my personal access tokens.)

[image]

And if I start the *`CI`* process manually, *`CI`* will crash like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72848127/how-to-solve-invalid-distribution-problem).

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

> ### ⚠️ Warning
>
> This answer recommends changing the default permissions for all action workflows to permissive instead of restrictive. From a security standpoint it is highly discouraged to do so. Instead, check the other answers on this Question for more secure alternatives.

Check if "Read and write permissions" are enabled in Settings -> Actions -> General -> Workflow permissions:

[image: Workflow permissions Setting]

Comment: If he's using his own personal token, why does this setting which claims to affect the permissions of GITHUB_TOKEN have any effect on his attempt to push?

Comment: Workflows are disabled on repo forks by default, you have to manually enable them. Good catch!

Comment: Github does not allow me to give read and write permission

Comment: Refer to: https://github.com/ad-m/github-push-action/issues/96#issuecomment-1647904286

Comment: @fccoelho you have to enable it on the top lvl first. (Organization, Account)

Answer (score 24):

If you're creating new files then you need to give explicit write permissions

```yaml
permissions:
  contents: write
```

Comment: This is a better solution than the highest voted one because it limits the permissions to the minimum.

Comment: The accepted answer was already set up for me - and this actually solved the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your workflow already has a permissions block, with which you've limited the permissions to `contents: read`. In order to publish to the Pages associated with your repo you'll need to add `pages: write` to that list.

> ### ⚠️ Warning
>
> Many of the other answers recommend changing the default permissions for all action workflows to permissive instead of restrictive. From a security standpoint we highly discourage people to do so.
>
> Instead of adding the equivalent of `permissions: write-all`, it's *much* better to rely on the default restricted read permissions and only add the exact write permissions you need.
>
> **DO NOT SET THIS TO "Read & write". DO NOT GIVE ACTIONS PERMISSIONS TO CREATE AND APPROVE pull requests**:
> [image]

In your case the following change to your workflow file should suffice:

```yaml
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write          # <-- Add this line
```

Comment: pages: write didn't work for me I had to use contents: write.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `persist-credentials: false` and `fetch-depth` is the issue. It is deleting the credentials of the git while checking out the repository.

You can try removing the line and try.

```yaml
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Comment: No，it has no help，and the crash is same.

Comment: I don't think it has connection with fetch-depth.