creyD/prettier_action - Process completed with exit code 128
I am having trouble in properly setting up my GitHub prettier action. I plan on using the creyD/prettier_action GitHub action to format incoming commits, but every time the code gets reviewed it always throws an error.
format-codebase.yml
name: Format Codebase w/ Prettier
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is attempting to ${{github.event_name}} to ${{github.repository}}
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  prettier:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE: /toolcache

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20
      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v3
        with:
          version: 8
          run_install: false
          standalone: true
          dest: ~/setup-pnpm
      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v4
        name: Install pnpm
        with:
          version: ^9
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install
      - name: Run Prettier
        uses: creyD/prettier_action@v4.3
        with:
          prettier_options: --write **/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,css} --tab-width 4
          prettier_plugins: "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"

result:
Run creyD/prettier_action@v4.3
...
Run PATH=$GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/node_modules/.bin:$PATH /home/runner/work/_actions/creyD/prettier_action/v4.3/entrypoint.sh
...
Installing prettier...
Checking plugin: prettier-plugin-tailwindcss
Prettifying files...
Files:
.prettierrc.js 403ms
app/globals.css 47ms
...
utils/utils.ts 6ms
Prettier result: 0
Deleting node_modules/ folder...
[unnamed 8204e68] Prettified Code!
 Author: unnamed-lab <unnamed-lab@users.noreply.github.com>
 36 files changed, 1437 insertions(+), 1404 deletions(-)
remote: Permission to unnamed-lab/ai-qr-generator.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/unnamed-lab/ai-qr-generator/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.

I want it to run the actions, check the codebase, format it with prettier, and then include it in the git commit so it can be later pushed to the main branch.

Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/creyD/prettier_action/issues/131

Also, relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72851548/permission-denied-to-github-actionsbot
